# Where can I get the LUIS subscription key?

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to create a simple chat bot on Microsoft Bot Framework and I want to add LUIS app ID and LUIS subscription key to my application.

Where can I get the subscription key?

[image]

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/sign-up

Comment: sorry but this link didn't help , I don't know where to find the subscription key ,would you please help me more?

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/LUIS-api/documentation/AzureIbizaSubscription) and this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/729beb66-bc4f-4acd-b858-ce0699e2b815/how-to-get-the-user-from-the-subscriptionkey?forum=azureapimgmt).

Comment: so in order to have access to my LUIS  model I need both the subscription key and the programmatic key which they've already provided it to me automatically , but what about the Dashboard (App Id: 41cc122a-65b2-4142-b787-2671b483d2d9) , can I use it instead of the subscription key ?

Comment: This is subscription ID not subscription key.

Comment: Yes I got it  , [luisModel (" subscription ID "," subscription key ")] right??

Comment: Yes, it is right.

Comment: You also get subscription key by usin [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscriptions).

Comment: oh last question what is the benefit of the programmatic key since I don't need to use it anyway ??

Comment: oh last question what is the benefit of the programmatic key since I don't need to use it anyway ??

Comment: Hi, you had better ask a new question about it.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? API?

Comment: I am finding myself just as confused as you are.

Answer (score 6):

I believe lately Microsoft has changed the structure of the portal so most of the links are not working.

> Where can I get the subscription key?

You can get the subscription key by going to

1. The "Publish App" link on the left,
2. Select staging from the "end point slot" under Publish Settings. (Don't know why doesn't it show while the option is Production. Maybe there are other ways to connect in the production environment)
3. Selecting the "staging" option will show an endpoint url which will have "subscription-key" field, which you can copy

> I want to add LUIS app ID

To get your luis app ID

1. Go to "My Apps" in "https://www.luis.ai/applications"
2. Click your app
3. Click settings from the options on the left
4. Copy the 36 character "Application Id"

Comment: This cleared things for me ! The documentation never explicitly mentions about publishing the app to get the end-point. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The followings are steps that worked for me:

1. Login into https://portal.azure.com
2. Search `luis` [image]
3. Create 1 **Language understanding** in **Cognitive Service** section
   [image]
4. Go to "My Apps" in https://www.luis.ai/applications
5. Select your app
6. Click on Change link nearing **Assigned endpoint key**
   [image]
7. Select available items in 3 comboboxes
   [image]

Here is the result that you could get subscription key
[image]
Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Subscription key: In azure create a new cognitive service -> Luis. In the new luis service, on the left you can find an option labeled keys. Use Key1 for everything.

API key: go to your luis.ai account, and select the key's tab. You need to link your luis subscription key here to link luis to your azure sub.

Comment: Use Key 1 for everything? Do you mean use Key1 for Subscription ID, Subscription Key etc? Please clarify I'm really struggling with this :(

Comment: That specifically means use Key 1 for all subscription key items you need to sync in the pipeline. Using a different subscription key for different items in the pipeline would cause it to not work. What specifically are you having trouble connecting in the pipeline? You should have an azure subscription key, luis app id, luis api key, botid

Comment: I'm getting "BadArgument, Invalid Subscription Key" when I add the key from Keys under Cognitive Services / Resource management / Keys.. And when I click on "Buy key on Azure" it starts to create a new Cognitive Services instance, which I have already done. Sorry but this is not intuitive..

Comment: I solved it by following the solution in this Stackoverflow answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997055/bad-argument-invalid-subscription-key-when-trying-to-add-key-from-azure

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate at this page https://www.luis.ai/keys where you will see "Programmatic API Key" it's your subscription key also known as "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key".

Comment: I'm getting a 404 now on this page.

Comment: Microsoft removed "home" part of the url

Answer (score 0):

I found this article on msdn that really explains the keys well https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2017/05/17/http-401-access-denied-when-calling-azure-cognitive-services-apis/

you can find your subscription keys the azure portal 
[Location of Subscription Key for Luis Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMRm0.png)

the application id can be found on the settings page of your app on the luis dashboard (start at www.luis.ai)
... all the details for this are in the article linked, but what I found was that:

1. Use the key as in the screenshot above
2. The region your azure resource for luis is in, should match the region that your luis application is in.

The resource is managed through the azure portal, the luis app is managed through the www.luis.ai homepage

As the article says, it can be quite confusing about what keys to use where, (especially when you first create the luis app you get a 'starter key' ... sorry for the waffle,

Answer (score 0):

The Subscription Key is the same as the Authoring Key (refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#using-luis-portal)). You can get the Authoring Key for your LUIS app by taking the following steps:

- Log on to luis.ai
- Navigate to the MANAGE menu
- Navigate to the Keys and Endpoints tab on the sidebar

[image: How to find your Microsoft LUIS Authoring Key]