# Bad Argument, Invalid Subscription Key when trying to add key from Azure

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to set up my LUIS app in luis.ai (because it seems like I can't set it up in Azure directly?). Anyway, I have created a Language Understanding Intelligent Service (LUIS) (preview) resource, but when I enter one of the keys from that resource into "My Keys" in luis.ai, I get this error: "Bad Argument, Invalid Subscription Key"

Also, I just tried to publish an app with the bootstrap key and got the following errors:

{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure your key does not correspond to the endpoint region you're trying to hit. Anyways, can't you use https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesLUIS?

Comment: I have exact same issue. I have tried subscriptions in West Europe and West US. I have used LUIS many times before so wondering if there is so issue.

Comment: I created a new one in the WestUS, waited 10 mints and it started working. Not sure why the others failed. I have added an issue to the User Voice.

Comment: It worked to go to eu.luis.ai and use west europe endpoint. Then the URI works, but I still can't make it work using the SDK... Any way to get the Android SDK to use the correct endpoint?

Comment: It also worked to create a new resource in WestUS and wait for 10 minutes before entering it into luis.ai. There it should probably work for the SDK as well. I would still like to know how to force the SDK to another endpoint.

Comment: Adding clarification notes for others encountering this: The West EU keys are bound to [EU.LUIS.ai](https://eu.luis.ai), attempting to use them in the [LUIS.ai](https://luis.ai) portal will indeed return the invalid key error. If you are using a West Europe subscription key for LUIS, you *must* use the European LUIS portal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As provided in comments, the solution is to use a correct end-point. This is not clear anywhere, but for the luis.ai portal, I have to use WestUS endpoint.

If I change to useing eu.luis.ai, I have to use the WestEU end-point.

Answer (score 2):

To use european LUIS endpoint within Bot Builder C# SDK, just modify Luis Model parameters as follows:

> [LuisModel("YOUR-LUIS-APP-ID", "YOUR-LUIS-EUROPEAN-KEY", domain:
>   "westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com")]

Note that you'll need to export your LUIS app over [EU.LUIS](https://eu.luis.ai/) in order to access the correct endpoint.

Hope it helps.